# What is the etymology of the phrase "leave me be"

Tags: etymology, phrases

The phrase is synonymous with "leave me alone".

I guess it's "leave someone/something be".

I've also heard this as "let me be".

Comment: It would be of great help if you looked it up online and post your findings. That way, we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

The expression is from the early 19tu century and it derives from an AmE usage of "leave" in the sense of "let":

***[Leave](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=leave):***

> - ***Colloquial use for "let, allow" is by 1840, said by OED to be chiefly American English.***  Not related to leave (n.). To leave out "omit" is from late 15c. To leave (something) alone is from c. 1400; ***to leave (something) be is from 1825***.

(Etymonline)

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leave%20me%20be%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cleave%20me%20be%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleave%20me%20be%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleave%20me%20be%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)***-  *leave me be*.